# Como instalar npm no servidor Heroku?

Tags: node.js, npm, heroku

Saudação para todos,

Recentemente enviei um projeto Laravel com VueJs para o servidor Heroku, e percebi que ele não reconheceu o meu arquivo App.js onde se encontra os métodos criados do VueJs, esse arquivo se encontra na pasta public, então não existia motivos para não funcionar, era para de fato funcionar.

Então percebi que eu não tinha instalado no servidor Heroku o **npm** e o **nodeJs**, para instalar esses caras no Heroku eu sei que posso utilizar o comando `heroku run "comando desejado"`, mas o problema é o seguinte:

O servidor Heroku utiliza Windows ou Linux?

Se for linux qual seria a forma mais correta para instalar esses caras?

Estou perguntando aqui porque não encontrei na documentação do heroku.

Comment: A configuração é feita pelo arquivo [Procfile](https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started/blob/master/Procfile) se não me engano

Comment: obrigado, vou verificar.